# Could not process parameters: int(2), it must be of type list, tuple or dict in python

Tags: python

I have two tables
StepNo (which is step number ) and stepText ( as every step has step text )

Now I try to retrieve a text from a database table to a text label I have in my UI
(I did insert them from another UI that insert the stepText And StepNo into the database
but I cant retrieve them

l stands for the label

```
def step2():
    result = search_step(2)
    l["text"] =['stepNo']
```

and those are the codes in db_setup

```
def add_to_step(stepText, stepNo):
    print(stepText)
    print(stepNo)
    sql = """INSERT INTO `steps`(`stepText`, `stepNo`) VALUES (%s,%s)"""
    c.execute(sql, (stepText, stepNo))
    result = c.fetchone()
    conn.commit()
    print("add to step: ", result)
    return result


def search_step(stepNo):
    
    print(stepNo)
    sql = """SELECT * FROM `steps` WHERE stepNo = %s"""
    c.execute(sql, stepNo)
    result = c.fetchone()
    conn.commit()
    print("selected step: ", result)
    return result
```

And this is the code of the label

```
# Create label
l = Label(window, text = "Change the paragraph font to Arial",)
l.config(font =("Calibri", 14))
l.pack(pady=40)

l.place(relx = 0.5,
                   rely = 0.5,
                   anchor = 'center')
```

and it gives me this error

```
File "c:\Users\maroc\OneDrive\Desktop\mouse features29-3\mouse features\stepsui.py", line 19, in step2
    result = search_step(2,)
  File "c:\Users\maroc\OneDrive\Desktop\mouse features29-3\mouse features\db_setup.py", line 49, in search_step
    c.execute(sql, stepNo)
  File "C:\Users\maroc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 562, in execute
    raise errors.ProgrammingError(
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Could not process parameters: int(2), it must be of type list, tuple or dict
```

I really need help for this situation as it is very important to me
thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for providing detail and example code in your question! Did you try Googling? When I searched Google for `Could not process parameters: int(2), it must be of type list, tuple or dict` provides https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67841760/python-mysql-valueerror-could-not-process-parameters as the first result, which directly answers your question.

Comment: Thankyou for kind words
I did see it but it didn't work for me sadly

Answer (score 2):

`execute` works for an arbitrary number of parameters, which means it doesn't know or care that your particular SQL command only needs one. You still have to provide a sequence (typically a tuple).

```
sql = """SELECT * FROM `steps` WHERE stepNo = %s"""
c.execute(sql, (stepNo,))
```

Comment: Hi
thnks for reply
i did what you said and there is a new error
2
selected step:  [(8, 'Change color to blueee', 2), (9, '1', 2), (10, '1', 2), (11, '1', 2), (12, '1', 2), (13, '1', 2)]
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\maroc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\maroc\OneDrive\Desktop\mouse features29-3\mouse features\stepsui.py", line 20, in step2
    l["text"] =result['stepNo']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str